# Are there iphone apps or automation for taking photos and sharing low resolution versions?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, camera

I need to take low resolution photos on iPhone5 like at 640*480, 320*240 etc. Low resolution photo is so that they can be uploaded easily. I don’t see a way to tell iOS to do this by default from the camera application.

- Only requirement is to upload as easily as possible low resolution photos. * No photo editing capability is necessary.
- If the photos can’t be processed in place, an automated way to reduce them and optionally delete the originals is ideal.
- most important is an easy way to get low resolution versions of all the photos shared out and uploaded.

So, any free, light weight, iOS app suggestion for taking low resolution photos with *rear cam* ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for taking a photo in a low resolution, as opposed to simply lowering the resolution after taking it? The opportunities for the latter are almost endless.  Not sure about the former....

Comment: No. For the sake of telling some reason, I can tell - ease. I would be happier, if could just take snap with some camera app and open google drive app to upload as opposed to taking a snap in default camera app, opening up another app to resize it and then opening google drive app to upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at [Simple Resize](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/simple-resize/id327776379?mt=8) which seems to do what you are looking for.

On iOS 12 - the app [Shortcuts by Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334?mt=8%20%E2%80%9CShortcuts%20by%20Apple%E2%80%9D) can automate all of this now for you.

- take a picture (preview or not)
- resize it
- save it to an album / share it to a shared album / save it to files (google / Dropbox / box / iCloud) / send it to an app

The last step can do just about anything you might want with images just taken and basically modify the camera to take reduced photos and optionally share them out as well if you don’t want to just have them taken.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest I have seen is by using [Camera+](http://campl.us/) by *TapTapTap*, which offers an "optimised" quality setting allowing for a maximum width/height of 1200 in the longest direction.  Others may shoot lower than this, but I am not aware of any specifically.

Comment: Thanks. But I needed free and lightweight app as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the front facing camera to achieve much lower resolution :)
There are also some fun apps that simulate the GameBoy camera or similar *very* low resolution cameras. But even they save the image scaled up, in order to actually be watchable (despite being pixelized).

For video there are apps that output in low resolution as well, like this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mrcamera/id546003651

Comment: Thanks. But specific mention to rear cam was in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use this app called LOWER, you can choose different resolutions from 120p to 720p, you can even do custom resolutions as low as 50x50
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lower-very-low-res-camera/id1265794764?mt=8